# Unable to cast System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In my code I have an interface - lets say its called `InterfaceName` and its implementation called `InterfaceImpl`. Now when I dynamically try to obtain the `InterfaceImpl` using the following code:

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance("ProjectName","ProjectName.Folder.InterfaceImpl");
InterfaceName in = (InterfaceName)obj; //Error pops up here
```

I get the following error

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle' to type 'ProjectName.Folder.InterfaceName'.
```

Any suggestions on what might be going wrong ?

Comment: Use the Unwrap() method.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[If you read the documentation about the method you are calling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx), it returns

> A handle that must be unwrapped to access the newly created instance.

Looking at the documentation of `ObjectHandle`, you simply call [Unwrap()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle.unwrap.aspx) in order to get the instance of the type you are trying to create.

So, I guess your real issue is... Why?

This method is designed to be called in another `AppDomain`, and the handle returned back to the calling `AppDomain`, where the proxy to the instance is "unwrapped".

What?  That doesn't explain why?

Only two types can cross an `AppDomain` barrier.  Types that are serializable (of which copies are created), and types that extend [MarshalByRefObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx) (of which *proxies* are created and passed).  `ObjectHandle` extends `MarshalByRefObject`, and so can cross that `AppDomain` barrier, whereas the type which they are representing may not extend MBRO *or* be serializable.  This method ensures you can get that type instance across the barrier, no matter what.

So, if you are just trying to instantiate a type, you might want to look at a different overload of CreateInstance.  Or just unwrap the result.

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance("A","A.B.C") as ObjectHandle;
InterfaceName in = (InterfaceName)obj.Unwrap();
```

Comment: You can also use [CreateInstanceAndUnwrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c4f1xde.aspx) that does the same job in one step (if default constructor exists)